# What exactly is ViewUserControl.ViewDataKey?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, viewdata

The documentation doesn't say much.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewusercontrol.viewdatakey(v=vs.98).aspx

What is the purpose of the ViewDataKey property of ViewUserControl and how can it be leveraged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ViewDataKey property can be used to specify the key of the item in the ViewData collection that you want to use for the ViewUserControl's Model. Basically, instead of just inheriting the parent's entire ViewData collection by default, the control will just get the item with the key you specify.

So, for example, if you put `ViewDataKey="EmployeeData"`, then it would look for an item in ViewData with the key "EmployeeData", and it would use that as the Model object for your ViewUserControl.

From what I can see, this is mainly used when using a declarative syntax for putting ViewUserControls inside a view. Meaning, instead of using `RenderPartial`, you use the old WebForm's syntax for registering a user control on a page, and have a server tag like `<MyApp:MyUserControl runat="server" ViewDataKey="EmployeeData" />`.

Comment: That was my intuition but I couldn't find documentation anywhere.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I think there's not much out there about it b/c most people don't use UserControls with declarative syntax (I haven't either).